# Obtaining identity from Pokhozhaev formula

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

From the classical [Pokhozhaev formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pokhozhaev%27s_identity), how can I obtain that the following identity holds for $u,v \in C^2(\bar \Omega)$?
$$
\int_\Omega (\Delta u(x,\nabla v) + \Delta v(x,\nabla v)) dx = \int_{\partial \Omega} ( \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}(x,\nabla v) + \frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu}(x,\nabla u) + (\nabla u, \nabla v) (x,\nu) )ds + (N-2) \int_\Omega (\nabla u, \nabla v) dx 
$$

Comment: by integration by parts :)